# Code of Conduct and Flags

Tags: discussion, flags, code-of-conduct

I know that there have been some other questions about the wording of the flags. I apologize in advance for subjecting you to yet another.

For some time, I have been uncomfortable with the flag entitled "Rude or Abusive" *on the post*. The new Code of Conduct offers an opportunity to upgrade this. The new Code certainly rules out rude or abusive behavior, but I believe it is more restrictive than that. I propose changing that flag to one that says "Violates the Code of Conduct". Is there any reason *not* to do that since behavior outside of the Code is prohibited?

You thoughts on this would be welcome.

Comment: Click the flag button on this comment to see the new CoC related flags. :) already live.

Comment: What you ask for seems to be implemented already.

Comment: The new flags appear to be comment only - not on questions or answers.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any reason not to [combine the categories into a single option] since behavior outside of the Code is prohibited?

Yes, breaking them up points out what is prohibited.  Users don't read everything, and certainly not anything that is a link to another page, so pointing out the common use cases explicitly is helpful.  I think it's worth emphasizing that unfriendly/unkind comments are actually violations of the CoC.  This is not true on many other public internet sites.  Mashing these flags into a single sub-option obfuscates the actual intentions of the CoC.

Also, there might be different end results based on the severity of comments that violate the "violates the CoC" flags.  Being unkind is not the same as harassing another user, and the two flagging options help communicate the severity and urgency of the offense.